# Nav Graph with Bottom Nav View along with other fragments

Tags: android, android-jetpack, bottomnavigationview, android-navigation-graph

I have a bottom navigation view with 5 tabs. I am using Nav Graph and linked the bottom nav view with the navigation graph.

My requirement is to have three out of the five tabs to work with Nav Graph and the other two with normal support fragment manager.

Is this something possible or I have to use a navigation graph for all five items. What's the best approach to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create different nav graphs for different tabs and in the activity, you need to mention all the nav graphs so that the navcontroller can handle them further.

And the best way to get more about this is to gaze upon [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#action_bar).

**Please feel free to ask if something is unclear.**

Answer (score 0):

No need to create different graphs. Nav component is updated. You can navigate to anywhere from the bottom navigation bar within the same graph.   [check here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui?hl=tr#bottom_navigation).